# Should I install driver of PK-635K model A4TECH WebCam?

Tags: drivers, webcam

I bought a WebCam that I mentioned in the question. There is an expression in its user manual like;

**Maximum Video Resolution: up to 1600*1200 pixel (software supported)**

And also, there is and expression in it like;

**The driver of this webcam does not need to be installed on Windows XP or later.**

I am a bit confused. I use Windows 10. Should I install its driver to enable 1600*1200 pixel resolution?

Comment: What resolution are you *currently* getting from the webcam?

Comment: It shows 640*480 as dimensions in the details tab of photo's properties when I take a photo with Windows 10 camera app

Comment: Software must support the camera in question to get the resolutions your asking about.  My best educated guess is that statement is talking about a software codec. Best ask the manufacturer what they mean though